# Eliminate left-recursion in unambiguous PEG grammar

Tags: javascript, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, peg, pegjs

I've read through a bunch of existing questions here on StackOverflow, but I can't get my grammar straight.

```
statement "Statement" =
    assignment / primitive / reference / operation
operation "Operation" =
    statement operator:operator statement
operator "Operator" =
    "+"
```

<sup>* Note that I might add more operator patterns to the operator rule (i.e. "==", "**", "/") later on. Thus, it could become more complex.</sup>

I'm actually using `PEG.js` instead of plain PEG here, hence the unconventional syntax.

The compiler complains to me about `statement` visiting the `operation` , which in turn visits the `statement` and so on, which leads to a possible infinite loop. This is commonly known as left-recursion.

For this particular case, I wasn't able to understand how I could resolve this issue. I didn't quite get the idea of the head and tail pattern for this scenario.

---

<sup>Note: I would like to re-use the `statement` rule in other rules as conveniently as possible. So splitting it in a dozen of individual rules as some work-around could be a solution, but won't really help me as an answer.</sup>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With the great help of some friend <sup>who understood the whole PEG parsing architecture within 10 minutes by the way</sup> , I was able to solve the problem for this scenario.

Let's ask this:

> In an operation in the form of `left+right` , will we ever have an assignment (of the form `a=b`) or another operation (of the form `a+b`) on the `left` side?

The answer is most likely no.

Hence, this grammar works:

```
statement "Statement" =
    assignment / operation / primitive / reference
operation "Operation" =
    (primitive / reference) operator statement
operator "Operator" =
    "+"
```

As you can see, I just inlined the `statement` rule in some kind by replacing it with the `primitive / reference` part from the `statement` rule, omitting the `assignment` and `operation` parts since we don't need them on the left side.

**This is just the solution. It's working fine.**

However, if you're wondering why parsing inputs like `1+2+3+4+5` works although we obviously don't allow recursive `operation` s on the left side of the `+`, be aware that we still allow them on the right side. And right-recursion is a totally valid thing in PEG.

Comment: That's fine for `+` because `a+(b+c)` has the same value as `(a+b)+c`. But if the operation is subtraction, you'll find that your parser produces a result different from what's usually expected.

Comment: I don't think this will behave unexpectedly. The parser is going to traverse the operation from left to right. In my real-world case, I've programmed PEG.js to return my operation in the form of `{left: primitive, right: {left: primitive, right: {left: primitive, right: primitive}}}` so that my program can traverse all chained operations from one element to the next where the right side of an operation is either another operation or a primitive at the end of the chain. Also, in my implementation you can use parenthesis so that `a-(b-c)` would still be possible. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: if you translate `3-2-1` to `{operator: '-', left: 3, right: {operator: '-':, left: 2, right: 1}}`, then it seems like that would evaluate to 2. Left-to-right evaluation, as taught in school, results in 0, and that's what Excel and most popular programming languages will produce. Expectations can vary from person to person, bit I think the most common expectation would be based on experience, so that 2 would be an unexpected result.

Comment: By contrast, `3 - 2 + 1` would evaluate to 0 using your chained grouping (if I understand correctly), but left-to-right calculation will produce 2. Of course, one could use parentheses to obtain the desired grouping, but having to use parentheses might also be unexpected.